# How can I set a network connection as metered?

Tags: windows-8.1

I would like to set a network connection as metered. I can't find how to do this; it seems to have changed in the upgrade from Windows 8 to 8.1.

I tried following the steps in [the official metered connection FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows-8/metered-internet-connections-frequently-asked-questions). However, when I open the connection, there is no *Data Usage* heading nor a *Set as a metered connection* option. I tried this on two different computers, both running Windows 8.1. I also tried doing this for both wireless and ethernet adaptors.

Here's what the connection screen looks like. I've cropped the empty space from the image.
[image: Network connection without metering options or information]

How can I set the connection to metered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that there were two separate causes of this:

#### Ethernet connections can't be set to metered

I discovered a note under the *What are the recommended settings?* heading that says:

> Ethernet network connections can't be set to metered.

#### Wireless *adaptors* can't be set to metered

I realised that only individual wireless networks can be set to metered. Wireless adaptors themselves cannot be. So to make a wireless connection metered, you have to first connect to the wireless network and then follow the normal instructions.

Comment: If a set a wifi ad hoc connection by hand, Do you know how set it as a metered connection? Normal instructions doesn't work.

Comment: @JoseNobile, I only really know how to do what I covered in the answer! Did you make sure that the connection was active before trying to change the setting?

Comment: Yes, the connection was active before try to set as metered connection.

Comment: @Sam You can actually change it. See my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's possible to set Ethernet and WiFi connection as metered connection. You just have to change them in the registry.

Here's how

1. Open registry editor `(Run --> regedit)`
2. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost`
3. Back up registry key `(File --> export)`
4. Take ownership of `DefaultMediaCost` key (Right click --> permission ---> advance --> change [owner])
5. Give yourself full control permission
6. On right hand side, double click on `Ethernet [REG_DWORD]`, change the value to "2"
7. Restart your computer
8. Done!

FYI: value 2 means metered, value 1 means unmetered, you can also change the metered setting for other connection type as well.

If you need full details, step by step (with screenshot), please see the reference link.

Reference : http://www.howtogeek.com/262477/how-to-set-an-ethernet-connection-as-metered-in-windows-8-and-10/